# C# start thread with function having delegate parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

```
public delegate bool FunctieCompara(int a, int b); this is the delegate
```

Simple function calls:

```
TyG.bubbleSort(TyG.max, TyG.Lungime, TyG.Secv);
TyG.bubbleSort(TyG.min, TyG.Lungime, TyG.secvMin);
```

I have a `Class Sorts` and in this class I have a lot of methods like

```
public void bubbleSort(functionDelegate f, int n, int [] v)
```

and much more sorts but with this parameters. In other class I have a instance of

```
Sortst tyg = new Sorts()
```

I want to create a thread

```
Thread Thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tyg.bubbleSort(functionDelegate)))
```

I didn't figure it out this thing works in my case, how can i use thread with a method that use a delegate, in my case the delegate is a `max/min` for comparing numbers for doing sorts in place in `v[]`. I want to make 2 threads for doing the both sorts `bubbleSort(max, n, v)` and `bubbleSort(min, n, v)` same time. That is what thread does anyway, anyhow can anyone help me a little please?

Comment: 1) How is `functionDelegate` defined? 2) What is your goal? Just to start two sorts in parallel or to measure/get results in some expected place?

Comment: start parallel sorts, the space of the result is taken care of , i use diferent v[ ] for max and min, i want to learn the thread using for this, that's the main ideea :)

Comment: I'm curious why you want to run this in two threads simultaneously. Given that you're using bubblesort, I'm guessing you're not doing it for speed. Is this for some sort of comparison between the sorts? Or is it just an example that you picked to try to learn multi-threading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var t1 = new Thread(
   o =>
   {
       tyg.bubbleSort(max, n, v1);
   });

var t2 = new Thread(
   o =>
   {
       tyg.bubbleSort(min, n, v2);
   });

t1.Start(); // start threads
t2.Start();

t1.Join(); // wait for both threads to finish
t2.Join();
```

Note that if you are sorting in place you should use different arrays (`v1` and `v2`) because otherwise the threads will be overwriting the same array.

If you are interested, also look over the `Task` construct of .NET 4.0.

Alternatively, if you want to be cool (.NET 4.0+):

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => tyg.bubbleSort(max, n, v1),
    () => tyg.bubbleSort(min, n, v2));
```

Comment: how to start them both same time ?

Comment: @TyGerX: I see this worked for you. It's nice to have a look also at the last example I posted, because it's a very compact way of doing things in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET Framework 4 and Task Parallel Library:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None);
var sorts = new Sorts();
FunctieCompara greaterThanComparer = (a, b) => { return a > b; };
FunctieCompara lessThanComparer = (a, b) => { return a < b; };
var sorterWorkers = new Task[]
     {
        factory.StartNew(() => sorts.BubbleSort(greaterThanComparer, 0, new int[] {})),
        factory.StartNew(() => sorts.BubbleSort(lessThanComparer, 0, new int[] {}))
     };

Task.WaitAll(sorterWorkers);
```

Comment: I think he wanted to start two bubble sorts with increasing and decreasing sort, not several different sorts. And for the case you described wouldn't `Parallel.Invoke` be more adequate?

Comment: THis is not a problem just pas different arguments

Comment: not but this helps :D i may do this , it is usefull to know thanks , this are not threads as i knew but seem to be usefull as threads , thx for the ideea